# Delphi Project with custom Style

Tags: delphi, styles

I want to create a Delphi project with a custom Style, like the below image.

[image]

As you can see, the MainForm is transparent, and there are some components inside of it.

How can I create this transparent MainForm?

P.S:I want to create VCL project and i drawn this image by Photoshop.

Comment: Just set `AlphaBlend = True` and `AlphaBlendValue = 128`.

Comment: By this way all components and left menu will be transparent too

Comment: The left menu looks like it is a separate window, there is clear space between the menu and the translucent area. And the controls on the translucent area appear slightly translucent themselves. So, using 2 Forms, one `AlphaBlend`'ed and the other not, you can easily replicate the appearance of that screenshot

Comment: I create this image by photoshop and this project doesn't exist in Delphi .and i want to create it by Delphi if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Firemonkey since you dont specify VCL or FMX.

You don't really need to create a style for this. Rather a simpler way would be to:

1. Set the form transparent property to `True`
2. Place a `TRectangle` on the form and make it align to `Most left` and adjust the color etc to your liking.
3. Place another `TRectangle` on your form and set the alignment to `Client`. You can then adjust the `Opacity` property for transparency, the `fill` property for `color` and then the `stroke` for the `border`.
4. I see a small space between the left and right in the photo. This can be done by setting a `margin left` value on the second `TRectangle` you placed.

Now this should look like you what want it to be provided you disabled the border of the form. There is 1 more thing we need to do to avoid having the controls show as transparent. We need to place a layout on the form. Not the rectangle. If you place the controls on the rectangle with opacity the controls will also be transparent. If you want the controls to have the same transparency value place it on the rectangle. Otherwise do the following:

1. Place a `TLayout` on the form. Not the rectangle.
2. Set the align property to Contents. This will make it overlap everything.
3. Set the `margin left` property of the layout to the width of the left rectangle you placed + the margin value of the client rectangle you placed to compensate for the little space.
4. Place your controls on the layout and they should show with default opacity.

One last thing to do is implement window drag. Assuming you disabled the border, your users will not be able to move the window at all since there is no border to drag. On the MouseDown event of the component you want the drag to start add the following code:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.rctngl1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  StartWindowDrag;
end;
```

You should be all done now.

EDIT: I made an example after posting this answer: [FMX Semi Transparent Form](https://github.com/AdriaanBoshoff/FMX-Semi-Trans-Form-Example)

Comment: i did all you said on FMX but components inside Tlayout are semi transparent.i dont want this component transparency changed.(looks like image in original color and visibility)

Comment: Make sure the parent of the layout is the Form and not the rectangle.

Comment: thanks.what is your suggestion for VCL? this route work only in FMX

Comment: Unfortunately it has been years since I last used VCL so I cannot give you an answer. With personal experience it would be easier to accomplish this task in FMX since you have a lot more freedom when it comes to customization.

Comment: @Adriaan: And the finished apps contain a lot more bugs... :/

Comment: Thats true as well but I found the more I developed the more I over came it. My latest project at the moment has no UI issues what so ever since I mostly made custom ListBoxes and other UI controls.

Comment: @HectorMoradi I edited my answer and included a working example project.

Comment: @Adriaan thanks. I made one sample according to your advise yesterday.but unfortunately i am looking for VCL and Not FMX.There are small components in FMX that i can use and i my project will not complete on FMX(due to little available components)